# How do I replicate this specific pack example in crystal?

Tags: crystal-lang

`Ruby` code sample:

```
"\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0002".unpack('N')[0]  #=> 2
```

How can I do this with `crystal` language?

Comment: See [this issue](https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/issues/276) on the Crystal GitHub.

Comment: Possible duplicated of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32725506/pack-the-contents-of-arr-into-a-binary-sequence-in-crystal

Comment: I think the question is not "how do I use unpack in crystal", it's "how do I replicate this *specific* pack example in crystal", which is not a duplicate. perhaps the question could be phrased more generically though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`IO#read_bytes`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.23.1/IO.html#read_bytes%28type%2Cformat%3AIO%3A%3AByteFormat%3DIO%3A%3AByteFormat%3A%3ASystemEndian%29-instance-method) method to read integers from many places. For example

```
io = IO::Memory.new("\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0002")
io.read_bytes(UInt32, format: IO::ByteFormat::NetworkEndian) # => 2
```

I would advise against using strings to store binary data though, reading directly from `IO`, or storing using the `Bytes` type is much more idiomatic Crystal.